Chrome displays the message "Unable to start camera" in a video conference through the Metered.ca iframe
I have developed a web application in C#/HTML/JS and I am using the embedded iframe feature from Metered Video SDK (metered.ca). The meeting is taking place with only 2 participants. Both are joining the meeting by accessing it through my web application.
The following error is occurring: when a participant accesses the website on my system through an Android device, the message "Unable to start camera" is displayed when entering the meeting. Those who are participating in the meeting through Windows have the image displayed normally. I have already tried to release several security features on Android and Chrome to try to solve it, without success.
What could be the problem? And how can I solve it?
Thanks in advance.
